# React cannot access state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to react cannot access state. Can someone explain?
I am trying to create bar graphs on the board and then whenever the button is clicked I want to perform one iteration of a sorting algorithm. I need the logic for: whenever the button is clicked, then I want to re render the squares based on their heights.Can someone push me in the right direction?

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';



class Square extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: null,
            heightSet: 3,
        };
    }
  render() {
    var divHeightStyle = {
    height: this.props.heightSet + 'em',
    };
    return (
      <button
        id={this.props.value}
        value={this.props.heightSet}
        style={divHeightStyle}
        className="square">
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Rectangle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    };


    reccheck = () => {
        this.props.check();
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <button
                className="rectangle"
                onClick={() => this.reccheck()} >
            </button>
        )

    }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const min = 1;
        const max = 80;
        const rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
        const rand1 = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
        const rand2 = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
        const rand3 = min + Math.random() * (max - min)

        this.state = {
            squares: [rand, rand1, rand2, rand3],
        };
    }
  renderSquare(i, y) {
    return <Square value={i} heightSet={y}/>;
  }
    check(){
        if(this.state.squares[0] > this.state.squares[1]) {
            alert('0 is bigger');
     }
    }
    renderRectangle() {
        return <Rectangle check={this.check}/>;
    }

    render() {
    const status = '';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(1,this.state.squares[0])}
          {this.renderSquare(2,this.state.squares[1])}
          {this.renderSquare(3,this.state.squares[2])}
          {this.renderSquare(4,this.state.squares[3])}
        </div>
          {this.renderRectangle()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Where are you unsuccessfully trying to access the state?

Comment: in the check function called whenever the button is clicked in the rectangle class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call to a function like you are doing, you are using a different `this`. You should either bind the correct this or use an arrow function.

Binding:

```
renderRectangle() {
    return <Rectangle check={this.check.bind(this)}/>;
}
```

or, arrow function:

```
check: () => {
    if(this.state.squares[0] > this.state.squares[1]) {
        alert('0 is bigger');
}
```